# There is an uncommon icon for my submission on EasyChair

Tags: peer-review, conference, paper-submission

I have submitted a manuscript via EasyChair. I assume that
iIt is still under review because I had no notifications of any sort.
When I click on my role on the main page, there is a link which allows me to download the manuscript I have submitted.
The icon is as shown below:

[image]

There is a paper icon with the number 1 in a red, rounded square on the lower-right corner.

However, normally, it is like this:

[image]

Which can be described as an open folder icon with a small black arrow pointing right on the upper-right corner.

Does this mean anything?

Comment: Just a guess that it represents something in the folder that you should read. I'd also guess that clicking the icon will open the document.

Comment: @Buffy It is true that when I click on the icon, I see the paper I have submitted. But there is nothing new to read.

Comment: Just a note, when I submitted a submission to Easychair that required two files the files had icons like that (but the other had number 2 on it). So maybe somehow there is also another file associated with your submission?

Comment: @Laakeri I think you are correct, I needed to upload an extra file. Can you please write this as an answer so that I can accept?